# Count the frequency of 2 words combination in all the rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas, count, nltk

I want to count the frequency of 2 words combination in all the rows of a column.

I have a table with two columns - The first is a column with a sentence while the other is the bigram tokenization of that sentence.

| Sentence | words |
| --- | --- |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'beautiful day' |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'day suffered' |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'suffered through' |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'cannot hold' |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'hold back' |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'back tears' |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'ash back' |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'back tears' |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'tears beautiful' |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'beautiful day' |

My desired output is a column counting the frequency of the words in all the sentences throughout the whole df['Sentence'] column.
Something like this:

| Sentence | Words | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'beautiful day' | 2 |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'day suffered' | 1 |
| 'beautiful day suffered through ' | 'suffered through' | 1 |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'cannot hold' | 1 |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'hold back' | 1 |
| 'cannot hold back tears ' | 'back tears' | 2 |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'ash back' | 1 |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'back tears' | 2 |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'tears beautiful' | 1 |
| 'ash back tears beautiful day ' | 'beautiful day' | 2 |

and so on.

The code I have tried repeats the first same frequency until the end of the sentence.

```
df.Sentence.str.count('|'.join(df.words.tolist()))
```

So not what I am looking for and it also takes a very long time as my original df is much larger.

Is there any alternative or any function in the NLTK or any other library?

Comment: why 'beautiful day' is at 2 ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie is because ‘beautiful day’ is present in both the first and last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

- Start by removing the quotes and whitespaces at the beginning and end of both `Sentences` and `words`

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("'", ""))
data["Sentence"] = data["Sentence"].str.strip()
data["words"] = data["words"].str.strip()
```

- Then set `Sentences` and `words` as string objects:

```
data = data.astype({"Sentence":str, "words": str})
print(data)

#Output
                          Sentence            words
0   beautiful day suffered through     beautiful day
1   beautiful day suffered through      day suffered
2   beautiful day suffered through  suffered through
3           cannot hold back tears       cannot hold
4           cannot hold back tears         hold back
5           cannot hold back tears        back tears
6     ash back tears beautiful day          ash back
7     ash back tears beautiful day        back tears
8     ash back tears beautiful day   tears beautiful
9     ash back tears beautiful day     beautiful day
```

- Count the occurrence of the given words in the sentence on the same row and store in a column e.g `words_occur`

```
def words_in_sent(row):
    return row["Sentence"].count(row["words"])
data["words_occur"] = data.apply(words_in_sent, axis=1)
```

- Finally groupby `words` and sum up their occurrences:

```
data["total"] = data["words_occur"].groupby(data["words"]).transform("sum")
print(data)
```

Result

```
                          Sentence          words    words_occur total
0   beautiful day suffered through     beautiful day           1     2
1   beautiful day suffered through      day suffered           1     1
2   beautiful day suffered through  suffered through           1     1
3           cannot hold back tears       cannot hold           1     1
4           cannot hold back tears         hold back           1     1
5           cannot hold back tears        back tears           1     2
6     ash back tears beautiful day          ash back           1     1
7     ash back tears beautiful day        back tears           1     2
8     ash back tears beautiful day   tears beautiful           1     1
9     ash back tears beautiful day     beautiful day           1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that you want a bi-gram count as contained in each unique sentence.  The answer for that already exists in the words column.  `value_counts()` is used to deliver that.

```
df.merge(df['words'].value_counts(), how='left', left_on='words', right_index=True, suffixes=(None,'_total')) 

                           Sentence             words  words_total
0  beautiful day suffered through       beautiful day            2
1  beautiful day suffered through        day suffered            1
2  beautiful day suffered through    suffered through            1
3          cannot hold back tears         cannot hold            1
4          cannot hold back tears           hold back            1
5          cannot hold back tears          back tears            2
6    ash back tears beautiful day            ash back            1
7    ash back tears beautiful day          back tears            2
8    ash back tears beautiful day     tears beautiful            1
9    ash back tears beautiful day       beautiful day            2
```